# Getting Valgrind on Windows 7

Tags: c, windows-7, valgrind, mingw-w64

I'm learning C and want to install Valgrind on my system, however when I attempt to install Valgrin I get an error saying `Valgrind is OS specific. Sorry` I'm running Windows 7, with Mingw64 GIT installed. I've done some research and found [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/valgrind4win/wiki/DevelopmentEnvironment/). According to that I need to run `sh ./configure --host x86_64 w64-mingw32` However when I run this I get the following output:

```
$ sh ./configure --host x86_64-w64-mingw32
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw64-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether ln -s works... no, using cp -pR
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw64-gcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw64-g++... no
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw64-c++... no
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw64-gpp... no
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw64-aCC... no
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw64-CC... no
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw64-cxx... no
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw64-cc++... no
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw64-cl.exe... no
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw64-FCC... no
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw64-KCC... no
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw64-RCC... no
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw64-xlC_r... no
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw64-xlC... no
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw64-ranlib... no
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for ar... /c/mingw/bin/ar
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for gdb... /c/mingw/bin/gdb
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for diff -u... yes
checking for a supported version of gcc... ok (4.7.2)
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-mingw64
checking host system type... x86_64-w64-mingw64
checking for a supported CPU... ok (x86_64)
checking for a 64-bit only build... no
checking for a 32-bit only build... no
checking for a supported OS... no (mingw64)
configure: error: Valgrind is operating system specific. Sorry.
```

So I thought, well I have I Mingw64, so may I should try that, same thing. Why is throwing the exception that I don't have Mingw, and how do I fix this?

Comment: As alternative you can take a look to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is saying that your OS is not supported and it found Mingw on your system which is not supported.

In general valgrind is not supported on Windows. Microsoft have their own version of glibc and their own kernel. Making a version of valgrind that can run on Windows would require a lot of porting work which no one is willing to make at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind compiled only for: {x86,amd64,arm32,arm64,ppc32,ppc64le,ppc64be,s390x,mips32,mips64}-**linux**, {arm32,arm64,x86,mips32}-**android**, {x86,amd64}-**solaris** and {x86,amd64}-**darwin** (Mac OS X 10.13

Is there a good Valgrind substitute for Windows? [Read more this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows)

You can try download **Code::Blocks IDE** with MinGW for Windows7 32/64 bit

[Official site here](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/binaries)