# How can I install dr memory on windows 10

Tags: c, windows, windows-10, dr-memory

How can I install ***dr memory*** on **windows** 10?
what is the **steps**, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a good Valgrind substitute for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows)

Comment: and [getting-valgrind-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019525/getting-valgrind-on-windows-7)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Valgrind on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019525/getting-valgrind-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to http://drmemory.org/
2. Click 'Are available for download'
3. Click 'Dr. Memory installer for Windows'
4. Wait until it finishes downloading
5. Run the installer with Admin privileges
6. Run Dr. Memory